# Ideas for new Drupal modules

Tags: support, meta

Myself being just a mere, beginner module developer, I'm not capable of writing advanced modules at this time. I often feel though like submitting an idea for a module for those who have some spare time and more knowledge than I have. Would Meta be a good place to submit such ideas? Maybe additional Meta section could be created to submit/list ideas and to denote those which have been taken care of by a developer.

Answer (score 1):

Meta sites are for questions about the main sites associated to them, or the meta sites itself. (There is just a meta site that is about all the Stack Exchange sites, and that is [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com), which right now is also the meta site for [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com).)

Questions about developing Drupal modules are on topic for *Drupal Answers*, as far as:

- you describe in detail what you are trying to achieve
- you describe what you tried, why it didn't work for you, or why the expected result was not the one you expected

Ideas about modules are not really on-topic for *Drupal Answers*, as they are not questions; they are discussions, but discussions are not allowed on the main sites. The only places where discussions are allowed is on the meta sites, where the topic is the one I reported at the beginning of this answer, and on chat rooms, such as [the one dedicated to *Drupal Answers*](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/327/drupal-answers).

The FAQ reports the following notes about the allowed questions on *Drupal Answers*:

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.
>
> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

Furthermore, it adds:

> If your motivation for asking the question is "I would like to participate in a discussion about […]," then you should not be asking here. However, if your motivation is "I would like others to explain […] to me," then you are probably OK. (Discussions are of course welcome in our [real time web chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/).)

That part of the FAQ is not specific to *Drupal Answers*, but it's generic, and valid for every Q&A site that is part of Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

I think that ideas for modules are probably best suggested either to maintainers you know personally (through correspondence in real life or via Drupal.org) or in the Drupal Groups.  There are Drupal Groups on nearly every topic and the groups are good at bringing together people with similar interests (geolocation, social networking, etc.) who may not always use the same groups of modules, giving great diversity to the discussion.

That said, ideas are a dime a dozen.  It's easy to think "I wish I had a piece of software that did this" but if you're not willing to put in the time and effort to write the code, why should someone else?

Comment: Thanks, now that I've been much more into Drupal and have submitted lots of feature requests, I appreciate initiative groups, esp. the way the authors of Media module do that. As per the question, it's not always that much black-and-white. There are visioneers and there are programmers. I spend time sketching out ideas, they translate it into code. So it's not about me "not willing" as I don't have to be a programmer.

Comment: Of course you don't have to be a programmer, but it's been my experiencing reading through the issue queues that there are far more people submitting ideas than actually writing code.  In my five years of Drupal experience, Drupal doesn't suffer from a lack of ideas, it suffers from a lack of people with the skills to implement their ideas (I would include myself in this group, so don't take it personally.)

Comment: My knowledge of PHP and Drupal APis allowed me only to write several formatters. Mostly because I found a bunch of decent example code. And I think that availability of properly written examples is crucial to make the ratio change.